# Cannot draw a line in Minecraft Fabric 1.20.1

Tags: java, rendering, minecraft-fabric

I attempted to draw a line from the player out 5 blocks in the X direction.
It is no where to be seen, from first person or even 3rd person view.
This was a client-side only mod.

Fabric MC setup:

```
minecraft_version=1.20.1
yarn_mappings=1.20.1+build.10
loader_version=0.14.22
```

Client Initializer Code:

```
@Override
    @Environment(EnvType.CLIENT)
    public void onInitializeClient() {
        WorldRenderEvents.END.register((ctx) -> {
            PlayerEntity player = MinecraftClient.getInstance().player;
            if (player != null) {
                BufferBuilder bufferBuilder = Tessellator.getInstance().getBuffer();
                RenderSystem.setShader(GameRenderer::getPositionColorProgram);
                RenderSystem.disableDepthTest();
                bufferBuilder.begin(VertexFormat.DrawMode.DEBUG_LINES, VertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);

                Vec3d playerVec = player.getPos();
                Vec3d finalVec = playerVec.add(5,0,0);

                bufferBuilder.vertex(playerVec.x, playerVec.y, playerVec.z).color(255, 0, 0, 255).next();
                bufferBuilder.vertex(finalVec.x, finalVec.y, finalVec.z).color(255, 0, 0, 255).next();

                Tessellator.getInstance().draw();
                RenderSystem.enableDepthTest();
                System.out.println("Rendered line from " + playerVec + " to " + finalVec);
            }
        });
    }
```

The line is printed but the line is not rendered.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you solve it?